# angularjs dynamic meta description refuse to show up

Tags: angularjs, seo

I am trying to implement dynamic SEO for my website, which involves dynamic `Meta` description for some pages. I've tried a number of ways to get the `Meta` description to show up, but to no avail; I would see the same result in console's elements view:

[image: Empty description screenshot]

**1) Setting meta description via a controller**

HTML:

```
<html lang="en" ng-controller="GlobalController">
    <head>
        <meta name="fragment" content="!">
        <meta name="description" content="{{metaDescription}}">
    </head>
    <body>
        etc...
    </body>
</html>
```

GlobalController

```
$scope.metaDescription = 'test description'; // Doesn't show in html
console.log($scope.metaDescription); // shows in console
```

---

**2) Using `$rootScope`**

HTML:

```
<meta name="description" content="{{metaDescription}}">
```

Controller:

```
$rootScope.metaDescription = 'test description';  // Doesn't show in html
console.log($rootScope.metaDescription); // shows in console
```

---

**3) Using a service** (based on https://weluse.de/blog/angularjs-seo-finally-a-piece-of-cake.html)

HTML:

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ SEO.metaDescription() }}">
```

Service:

```
angular.module('core').service('SEO', function() {
    var metaDescription = '';
    var metaKeywords = '';
    return {
        metaDescription: function() { return metaDescription; },
        metaKeywords: function() { return metaKeywords; },
        reset: function() {
            metaDescription = '';
            metaKeywords = '';
        },
        setMetaDescription: function(newMetaDescription) {
            metaDescription = newMetaDescription;
        },
        appendMetaKeywords: function(newKeywords) {
            for (var key in newKeywords) {
                if (metaKeywords === '') {
                    metaKeywords += newKeywords[key].name;
                } else {
                    metaKeywords += ', ' + newKeywords[key].name;
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
SEO.setMetaDescription('here is a test description'); // Doesn't show in html
console.log(SEO.metaDescription()); // shows in console
```

---

Could someone please kindly point me to the possible issue and solution?

Comment: hi , have you got any solution yet ? i'm looking for the same solution . thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing the description directly in the $ routeProvider , you might be setting like this:

App.js

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        title: 'Home page',
        metaDescription: 'description of page home',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
       })
       .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
  }); 

     myApp.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function( $location, $rootScope, ) {
           $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current) {

        $rootScope.metaDescription = current.$$route.metaDescription;
             });
         }]);
```

Index.html

```
<meta name="description" content="{{metaDescription}}">
```

Note. Writing so they are visible to Google's crawlers, after the page is indexed .